# Using named group to call function in view django

Tags: django, url

I don't know if something like this is possbile but I would like to call a function based on the named group value in the urls.py config.

This is what I have been looking at

url.py snippet

```
url(r'^ajax/ValidateLogin/(?P<funcname>\w{13})/$', Validate),
```

views.py snippet

```
def checkUsername(request):
  user = User.objects.get(username=request.POST.get('username',''))

  if user == None:
    response = simplejson.dumps({'success':'True','validate':'True'})
  else:
    response = simplejson.dumps({'success':'True','validate':'False'})
  return HttpResponse(response,content_type='application/javascript; charset=utf-8')

def Validate(request,funcname):
  return  funcname(request)
```

This just returns that unicode object isn't callable which I understand but how do I then convert it to call the view function check username? An example of url that should call this is ajax/ValidateLogin/checkUsername

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

```
remote_function_calls = {
    'check_username' : check_username,
}

def Validate(request, funcname):
    try:
        return remote_function_calls[funcname](request)
    except KeyError:
        response = http.HttpResponse("Invalid function")
        response.status_code = 403
        return response
```

#### Another method to define which functions are valid

```
def valid_function(request):
    return http.HttpResponse("This function may be called remotely")    
valid_function.remote_call_valid = True

def erase_everything_function(request):
    world.delete()

valid_functions = dict([(k, v) for k, v in globals().iteritems() if
    getattr(v, 'remote_call_valid', None) == True])
```

Comment: Thank you this will work. I was hoping there would be a more dynamic way of doing this.

Comment: It could be a little more dynamic but I still think you'd need to specify *somewhere* which functions may be called from the module scope. Another method would be to add an attribute to each valid function and filter the `globals()` dictionary. - updating with idea

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
def Validate(request,funcname):
    return locals()[funcname](request)
```

Although this kind of thing is a bit of a security risk since any user can call any arbitrary function available to python by passing the right "funcname".

Comment: locals() scope wouldn't have the functions